# ProtonMail turn off auto-copy of conversation

Tags: account-management, protonmail

When I reply in ProtonMail it automatically includes a copy of the entire conversation so far. I can manually delete all of that every time, but is there a way to turn off this behaviour?

It's especially useless behaviour because ProtonMail already has a conversation styled layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there isn't any option in ProtonMail which could turn-off this behaviour. (fyi it's a standard behaviour supported by majority email providers - Gmail included)

Your options are to manually delete it each time you wish (as you mentioned) or submit a request for a new future: **https://protonmail.com/support-form**

Comment: Eh no, Gmail just appends the new e-mail to the bottom. It doesn't copy-paste the whole mail history in each e-mail. Outlook and hotmail don't do this either. I'm aware this is an e-mail standard. Hotmail used to do it, but no more. I'll make a feature request.

Comment: I believe Gmail does include the whole email history in each email, but the Gmail UI collapses and hides all previous messages in the email and only the new part is visible. If you look closely, you'll see three faint gray dots you can click in an email body to show the hidden parts of the email.